# Url rewrite rules not redirecting

Tags: url-rewriting

I have my .net mvc website hosted in liquid web cloud. I wanted to redirect all website users if they enter the following url http://example.com,http://www.example.com,https://example.com

to https://www.example.com ( i.e. consistent url not matter how they enter)
i tried the following code in web.config but no luck.

```
    <rule name="Redirect Non WWW" stopProcessing="true" > 
    <match url="^(http\.)(.*)$" />  
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />  
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^https://www.example.com$" />  

          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```

Domain is already registered as www.example.com and SSL is enabled on the domain.

Comment: <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll">>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  
    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>   no effect

Answer (score 0):

You have used `MatchAll` and also set the condition that url should have `https` to start rediretion! Just change it to having `http` instead:

incorrect:

```
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^https://www.example.com$" />
```

correct:

```
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^http://www.example.com$" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to force a redirect to use HTTPS, (.*) will match all URLs and you can set the pattern to off.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirection" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

**Update**:
There isn't any problem with method 1, but also adding this for those who visit this post later.

> Method 2:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirection" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Maybe you've set up another rule to redirect, remove all other redirects and try again

Comment: I have only one rule and  if we don't give any condition apart from https patern off, then redirected url will also match the same rule (.*) so it will lead to multiple redirect.

Comment: The sample I have submitted is from the official documentation and it works, here's the link: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Anyways add this one line inside conditions, which many users using aws have found to be useful `<add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />`

Comment: I tried this as well       <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll">>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  
    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>